# Admin Add a New Button in Form Container which send form to other controller

Tags: magento2, admin, blocks, adminform

In magento 2 Admin i have create a form using a NON UI component method that is using block classes.

I wanted to submit this form to two different controller. By default it sends data to save controller. How can i send this data to other controller too. For example Send Controller

Comment: Why you send data to another controller?

Comment: Because that what i need to do.